# Rails: Can db queries be run at will through console AFTER deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.2, console

I am about to build an admin interface for my website. Before I do that, I;d like to know if (as site admin) I can run db queries at will through the console after deploying my app. The reason I am asking is that I am thinking of capturing certain queries in my controller that will give results such as total users, total males, total females, total users from City A, total males from City A, users joined in Month X and many more similar queries.

Instead of capturing these in variables and then displaying the results in my admin interface, can I just go in the console and do these queries daily??

Note - I have never deployed an app so I am not sure how console access works post deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. If you own your server you can just enter rails console and do everything you want.

If you have an hosting like heroku you can run rake tasks that print the info you need